# C - realloc error when changing member in struct

Tags: c, struct, realloc

I get this error when trying to change an int member in a struct:

> Error in `./resize': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000006bc010 ***
>   Aborted (core dumped)

My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int size;
} fich;

int main(){

    int i = 1;
    fich * ptr = NULL;

    while(i < 5){
         fich* newptr = realloc(ptr, i * sizeof(fich));
         if(newptr != NULL)
             ptr = newptr;
         else return 1;

         ptr[i].name = "stufs";
         ptr[i].size = 1;

         i++;
    }

return 0;
}
```

I can change name just fine, but not size. What's going on?

Comment: Your allocated array has `i` entries. That means that `ptr[i]` is out of bounds. Writing to this illegal position just one item after the valid range may corrupt internal data of the allocation the system. Start with `i = 0` and allocate `i + 1` items. (Better yet, allocate all five items at once.)

Comment: @MOehm Oh my god, I'm so stupid. Thank you!! But why was there no error when changing the char*?

Comment: No need to castigate yourself, many errors look stupid in hindsight. As to your question: You can't know what exactly happend, it's undefined behaviour. (That's also the reason why you should learn to spot such undefined behaviour in code.)

Comment: @MOehm Hmm, I see. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, arrays start at index 0. Your first iteration with `i=1` allocates space for one fich, which is `ptr[0]`, not `ptr[1]`.

Classic off-by-one in combination with buffer-overflow :-)

Comment: Yes, this was it, like MOehm said in the comments. Thanks :)